# VB.NET reading CSV and adding new fields conditionally

Tags: vb.net, csv

When running debugger, i am getting the following error,

A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in HSL File Config.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in HSL File Config.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
The program '[14044] HSL File Config.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

i have checked the csv data file im loading is in fact 30 columns long and no blank lines. there are however some blank fields.

```
    Dim FileName = tbOpen.Text
    Dim fileout = tbSave.Text
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
    Dim output As New List(Of String)

    For Each line In lines
        Dim fields = line.Split(","c)
        If fields(0) = "R62167" Then
            ReDim Preserve fields(fields.Length)
            fields(31) = "9991"
        End If
        If fields(0) = "R62193" Then
            ReDim Preserve fields(fields.Length)
            fields(32) = "1999"
        End If
        If fields(2) = "2249" Then
            fields(2) = "0000"
        End If

        output.Add(String.Join(","c, fields))
    Next
    File.WriteAllLines(fileout, output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use redim

```
If fields(5) = "4WK" Then
    ReDim Preserve fields(fields.Length)
    fields(6) = "NewDate"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks Mukul Varshney, you have saved my bacon! amazing. cant believe it was something so simple :)

Comment: thanks for the info, but getting errors with larger data sets (around 30 columns)

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Will suggest you to define fields array with an expected maximum columns, outside the for loop. use a variable count to update the fields value. fields(counter) = "NewDate" counter = counter +1, once you add a value, or declare fields as a List. This will be similar to what @FloatingKiwi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Fields` as an array try it as a list as these are resizable.

```
Dim fields = line.Split(","c).ToList()
```

then you can do

```
If fields(5) = "4WK" Then
    fields.Add("NewDate")
End If
```

Comment: Thanks both. this seems to work well with small amounts of data, but once i try it with the real file im trying to manipulate i get 
    A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll errors
 any ideas?

code snippit to follow

Comment: Dim FileName = tbOpen.Text
    Dim fileout = tbSave.Text
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName)
    Dim output As New List(Of String)

        For Each line In lines
            ' version 1   Dim fields = line.Split(","c)
            Dim fields = line.Split(","c).ToList()
            If fields(28) = "ZIPSPEED" Then
                fields.Add("NewDateD")
            End If

            output.Add(String.Join(","c, fields))
        Next
        File.WriteAllLines(fileout, output)

Comment: it seems to fail on any field other than fields(0) if that helps?

Comment: I suspect you have a blank line in your file so splitting it yields just a blank string. So test whether your fields has at least 29 fields before processing the fields. Please get acquainted with the debugger as these issues are quicker to fix yourself than posting on SO and waiting for a reply

Comment: Thanks @FloatingKiwi, I'll try and become more familiar with that. 

its worth noting that my data file (CSV) has at least columns of data and no blank lines. 

A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in HSL File Config.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in HSL File Config.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
The program '[14044] HSL File Config.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Comment: Your asking for an element that doesn't exist. When you split the string you didn't end up with your expected number of strings. Use a debugger and look at the values, it'll be blatantly obvious what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help @FloatingKiwi

Comment: i think i have got to the bottom of it, Thanks again for your efforts. i can appreciate it must be very frustrating for you to deal with people with far infverior knowledge.